(trapped) error reading bcrypt version v.4.1.2
I am programming an API with FastApi and also use the module bcrypt==4.1.2  When executing it I get the following error:
...
INFO:     Finished server process [24084]
INFO:     Started server process [3256]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
(trapped) error reading bcrypt version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xnet_api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\passlib\handlers\bcrypt.py", line 620, in _load_backend_mixin
    version = _bcrypt.__about__.__version__
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute '__about__'
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53814 - "POST /user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

In an old Github post i read that this is a bug with bycrypt: https://github.com/langflow-ai/langflow/issues/1173  "Hey. This is a bug on passlib. I'll try to push an update on that ASAP. The issue is bcrypt's version has to be pinned at 4.0.1 until they fix it in passlib." - on Dec 4, 2023
However, this was a long time ago and the error still exists.  When I use version 4.0.1, the error no longer occurs. However, version 4.1.2 is already available and I would like to use the latest version.  My question is, is there a way to fix the error? Can I simply ignore the error?    Thank you very much for your help  mfg

There is no magic way to fix this error (if it even is an error, it looks like just a warning?). Either you downgrade bcrypt, or you submit a PRs to passlib to fix it (or maybe langflow, since passlib doesn't seem to be maintained anymore).

you can always edit source code D:\xnet_api\.venv\Lib\site-packages\passlib\handlers\bcrypt.py on your computer and add _bcrypt.__about__.__version__ - and it will fix this problem for you. But you have to remember to keep this code and not update modules in venv

In the .venv\Lib\site-packages\passlib\handlers\bcrypt.py file change the below line
version = _bcrypt.__about__.__version__

to
version = _bcrypt.__version__


This is only a temporary solution that's working until you reinstall your local environment OR build the project for deployment in a docker image using poetry/requirements.txt, I strongly advice to take a look this comment: https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/issues/684#issuecomment-1902590553      Generally speaking, modifying files in your virtual environment is not a good practice since you'll not be able to track your changes using e.g. git. (Adding the venv to your git to solve this isn't a good practice either)

Setting the bcrypt version to "4.0.1" will solve this for me.
